# What does “the New York egoscape” mean?

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

I was interested in the word “egoscape” used in the following paragraph of the *New Yorker* magazine’s (March 14) article written by David Remnick under the title “American Demagogue”:

> “For a long time, Trump, with his twenty-four-karat skyscrapers, his
>   interesting hair, and his extra-classy airline, was a leading feature
>   of **the New York egoscape**. The editors of the satirical monthly Spy
>   covered him with the same obsessive attention that Field & Stream pays
>   to the rainbow trout.”

I can’t find the word *egoscape* in either Oxford or Cambridge English Dictionary. Nor does Google Ngram register this particular word.

While [Murukan](http://murugan.org/research/valluvan2.htm) says "egoscape" means “inward pilgrimage of an individual,” it doesn’t seem to fit the context of the above paragraph to me.

What does “egoscape” mean? Does it pass current?

Comment: What does "ego" mean?  What does the suffix "-scape" usually imply?  Put them together.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scape

Comment: Hotlicks. I can easily understand scape of Landscape, seascape, mountainscape which are all phisical, but my imagination doesn't reach egoscape which is immaterial and menta without size. Maybe I'm too old to come to the association of words and merely confused by http://murugan.org's definition. .

Comment: The Murugan reference is irrelevant.  That usage is unknown to the average English reader and is only significant to members of that sect.

Comment: To paraphrase Yogi Berra, English is ninety percent mental and the other half is physical.

Comment: Can we say Washington egoscape, Beijing egoscape, Wall Street egoscape, and Silicon Valley egoscape?

Comment: I expect that you could. Most places, and certainly most places that attract the wealthy and powerful, would have a collection of individuals who made up that locale's egoscape.  It the collection of ego-driven individuals that make up the egoscape not necessarily the place.

Comment: How could I tell who was being written about when I saw this on the Hot Network Questions sidebar?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Why do you need to know who is being written about?  There are plenty of oversized egos in New York.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the question that attracted more than 400 views and earned 6 upvotes (minus 1 downvote) and one favorite question vote needs to be close-voted, though I don't blame downvotes. I doubt if it's non-native speaker bashing or somewhat prejudiced.

Comment: The close votes are for failure to do research, and those voters have a point.  A little Googling would have found your answer.  Your one "excuse" is that you were misled by the bogus "egoscape" link.  (You got the views and some of the up votes because your question got randomly added to the "hot questions" list.  This generally distorts the numbers.)  (And, by the way, you need to find out how to properly add links to a question or comment.)

Comment: @Hot Licks. I did more than “a little” research. I googled and consulted CED and OED (Maybe I should have checked Webster and Collins too). Ngram carries “landscape” but not “egoscape.” I as non-native English speaker am unable to determine if Mulcum site who was a single provider of the meaning of “egoscape” in my research  is a bogus or not, though I thought its definition is irrelevant to the context of the quoted paragraph. 
I’m on EL&U for more than 4 years, and the record of budges I earned shows that I’m not so terribly idle researcher as you think.

Comment: Cont. I made my point.  I don’t want to argue anymore on this issue.

Comment: You asked for an explanation and I gave it to you.

Comment: @HotLicks I think the fact that, in my view, the two answers posted to this question do not convey the correct meaning proves the value of Yoichi's question, and I can't understand why anyone would want to close it (what is the site for otherwise?). Yes, there is now a good definition returned as the top result on Google (albeit with two distinct meanings, of which the selected answer below has wrongly chosen the second). However, I suspect it had not been indexed by Google at the time the question was asked, since the page was only added recently.

Comment: @atkins - It's legitimate (and even recommended, I suspect) to close vote a question for lack of research even when there are several excellent answers -- doing research is *required* before asking questions such as this one.  But if you actually look at what was said, the OP asked why he'd gotten close votes, and I replied.  I did not pass judgment on the question personally.  (And if you think there's not been a proper answer to the question, why have you not offered one???)

Comment: I repeat I don’t want to readdress “did or didn’t research issue.” It’s an utterly subjective issue - How can you prove that I didn't make enough research?. But whatever you tenaciously droll on, I’m quite satisfied with the legitimacy and necessity of having asked this question is well supported and evidenced by 528 viewers, 6 up-voters, 3 favorite question scorers. This isn’t a mediocre number.  I don’t think all those viewers and up-voters are nuts as you think.
When I researched the word on google ten days ago, there was only one answer available from @mulkam, which you said bogus.

Comment: Cont'd: When I googled “egoscape,”yesterday for curiosity and reconfirmation, I found this, my own question on the top twice in a row.. Today I found the new answer from ‘wordpy com,’ which defines ‘egoscape’ as ‘the egos within a particular geographic area; the extent of a person's ego’ above my question, “ What does “the New York egoscape “ mean ...” You say "do research." I did research. This is the exact google research result. Don't give a heedless kick to others. This is the last of my word. No answer required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any word you see that ends in *-scape*, Oishi-san, refers to [a scene or view of something](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-SCAPE) [TFD]. Thus we get amalgams like

> landscape
>   seascape
>   dreamscape

and so on. The point is, these are usually spacious, sweeping vistas, the size of everything you can see with your eyes in one direction.

What Remnick is doing is describing Trump's ego as something as broad and sweeping and spacious as a seascape or landscape. In other words, he's artfully saying that Trump and his ilk (rich, upscale New Yorkers) have gigantic egos.

Comment: Following your definition of _-scape_ words, I think the sense might be not that Trump is himself an egoscape, but instead that Trump is a prominent figure in the social landscape of inflated egos in New York. Not only that, but his ego, like so many others', manifests in the physical cityscape in the form of Trump Tower.

Comment: @AdamBrown I believe that your comment is the most accurate answer here - I think you should post it as an answer in its own right.

Comment: @atkins I took you suggestion and proposed an answer.

Comment: Though for people who don't live there, it's not just "Trump and his ilk" who form the New York (City) egoscape.  It's more like he's Pike's Peak in the Colorado landscape.

Comment: Nicely put. Funny as well.

Answer (score 5):

It's clear enough that the suffix *-scape* refers to a [scene or vista](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-SCAPE). This form is derived from *landscape* and is used analogously in words like *cityscape*, *moonscape*, etc. In this case, *egoscape* refers to the social environment — metaphorically, the ego landscape — of New York City.

In the case of this quotation there is a clever double-meaning in that Trump's ego, with *ego* used pejoratively to connote an excessive sense of self-worth, manifests in the physical cityscape. (Trump is a developer, known for his extravagant skyscrapers.) So *egoscape* is both a metaphor for New York society as a whole, and a critique of the built environment. The sense of this second meaning is that the actual landscape of New York City is a reflection of the over-sized egos who inhabit it.

Answer (score 3):

Egoscape is this context refers to the mental picture New Yorkers have of their city, themselves and their place in the world.

Every city, state and town thinks it is special, but for New Yorkers, it's New York and the ROW (Rest of the World).  For proof of this, see the *New Yorker* cover, *View of The World from 9th Avenue*, shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_of_the_World_from_9th_Avenue)

Today's Washington Post (Thu, April 14, 2016) has an article on its front page, above the fold, titled "Trump's Slice of the Big Apple".  The gist of the article is that

> To these New Yorkers, the reason for backing the mogul is clear: He's
>   one of them.

Comment: This seems to imply that the *ego* in *egoscape* refers to all New Yorkers and their concept of themselves as representative individuals in their home town.  But I don't think that's the meaning.  The "egoscape" of New York is the array of famous NYC egotists who make for as characteristic view of the city as the NYC skyline makes for the NYC cityscape.